# WMS not rendering properly within API

Tags: qgis, wms, api, rendering, qgis-cloud

I am working with simple layers using lines and polygons in QGIS 3.22.11 and publishing them as a WMS to QGIS Cloud.  The Map Viewer in QGIS Cloud displays them perfectly but when I bring the WMS into another application the display is chopped and not rendering properly.  The layers and project are all in the same projection EPSG: 4326. The API meets the requirements of QGIS Cloud. Any suggestions?

[image: wms rendering failure]

Comment: which other application?  Is it trying to tile the WMS, if so is there an option to turn off the tiling?

Comment: @nmtoken The WMS is being loaded into GMap.NET https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET and it is not possible to turn off the tiling. Is there anything that you recommend that I do to the map prior to it being uploaded as a the WMS to make the rendering smoother?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the rendering, the issue is with the tiling, or specifically with the GMap.NET applications ability to make the correct GetMap requests and stitch the images together.